# When adding a new user without a secondary address, can G Suite still auto send the new user's login info?

Tags: g-suite-administrator

The final step in G Suite's "Add a user" is:

> (Optional) To do any of the following, click **More actions** and choose
>   one of these options, or click **Done**:
>
> ...
>
> - Email login info to this user. If you entered a secondary email address for the new user, it appears automatically in the Email field. Use the secondary email,
>     or update it to another email, then click **Send** to send the new user their login info.
>
> <sub>-https://support.google.com/a/answer/33310</sub>

But what if you did **not** enter a secondary email? Do you still get a chance to input an address to receive the login info without keeping it permanently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes, the box will still be there. It will just be empty, letting you write a manual one-time address.

[image: Email login info]

[image: Enter any e-mail address]